# parsing SVG in webpack

Tags: svg, webpack, node-modules, yarnpkg, loader

I have created a project  on Symfony 5. I am receiving an error in webpack when I run 'yarn build'. I am trying to fix it from few days but without success, so I decided to ask for some help :)

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

I have enabled postCssLoader in my webpack.config and created postss.config.js in my root directory

```
.enablePostCssLoader()
```

**postss.config.js File**

```
module.exports = {
plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-svgo'),
    require('postcss-inline-svg'),
    require('postcss-write-svg'),
  ]
}
```

And here is a sample of svg I am trying to write in my css

```
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' width=\'8\' 
     height=\'8\' viewBox=\'0 0 8 8\'%3e%3cpath fill=\'%23fff\' d=\'M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538- 
     1.55L0 4.26l2.974 2.99L8 2.193z\'/%3e%3c/svg%3e')
}
```

Comment: please provide the error as text rather than an image as an image is not searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error transfers code verbatim, then there are two line breaks (and indentation) that makes the property invalid (see "CRLF": `..width=\'8\'CRLF     height..` - this one you can backslash-escape in CSS, and `..1.538-CRLF     1.55L..` - this one with indentation separates numeral making path data invalid - you have to remove all whitespace between minus and digit). If this is it, simply removing line breaks (and suprefluous whitespace) should fix it:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' width=\'8\' height=\'8\' viewBox=\'0 0 8 8\'%3e%3cpath fill=\'%23fff\' d=\'M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26l2.974 2.99L8 2.193z\'/%3e%3c/svg%3e')
```

If code snippet you provided is not directly from your source code, then you have probably some formarrter breaking it in the process (?)

---

N.B. you don't usually have to escape SVG datauris so much, you could go with `url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8' fill='%23fff'><path d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26l2.974 2.99L8 2.193z'/></svg>")` (i.e. the only escaped sequence is `#`->`%23`) and most interpreters should pick it up just fine.  I'm not sure about your build stack, but I'd guess that "safe over-escaped format for obsolete IEs" could be produced as the build result; and if you use preprocessor you can embed 'dataurized' external resources, what could prevent such formatting accidents. (Ah, that's probably what the `postcss-inline-svg` is doing for you.)

Comment: Thanks mate this helped a lot, I made it work with your second example and I dont needed to enable .enablePostCssLoader() anymore